# Equivalence of two methods to obtain $\sin \theta \geq 1$ with a complex $\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, proof-verification, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

When evaluating the function $\sin \theta$ with a complex angle $\theta$, a real value $A \geq 1$ can be obtained in two ways.

1. Considering $\theta = i \log \left[ -i \left( A + \sqrt{A^2 - 1} \right) \right]$, as stated in [this page](https://www.quora.com/Can-the-values-of-sin-and-cos-be-more-than-1/answer/Malay-Parmar). After the substitution of $\theta$,

$$\sin \theta = \frac{e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta}}{2i} = A$$

2. Considering $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - iB$. This way,

$$\sin \theta = \cosh B$$

I want to prove that the two methods are equivalent.

**My attempt:**

I applied the [inverse hyperbolic cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_cosine) definition:

$$\cosh B = A \Rightarrow B = \mathrm{arccosh} A = \log \left[ A + \sqrt{A^2 - 1} \right]$$
$$\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - i\log \left[ A + \sqrt{A^2 - 1} \right] \label{a} \tag{1}$$

In method 1, $\theta$ can be rewritten as

$$\theta = i \log \left[ -i \left( A + \sqrt{A^2 - 1} \right) \right] =\\
= i \log \left( \frac{A + \sqrt{A^2 - 1}}{j} \right) = i \left[ \log \left( A + \sqrt{A^2 - 1} \right) - \log i \right] = \\
= i \left[ \log \left( A + \sqrt{A^2 - 1} \right) - i \frac{\pi}{2} \right] =$$
$$=i \log \left( A + \sqrt{A^2 - 1} \right) + \frac{\pi}{2} \label{b} \tag{2}$$

**My question:**

In my attempt, \ref{b} doesn't match \ref{a}. Why? What is wrong?

---

This question is related to a Physics [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/442582/value-of-complex-angle-in-snells-law) about Snell's law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they match. Just note that$$(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}):\sin\left(\frac\pi2-z\right)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2+z\right)=\cos(z).$$